# when zoom in browser cause one div container expand, how to adjust other div container length to keep the at a same bottom line?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, primeng

HI I am now working on a webpage.In the page I have a left part and right part. The right part has a table view, and the left part just some buttons. it looks like this:
[image]

It looks good now. but when I zoom in my browser to like 150%, 160%..., the right part(table) will expand its bottom vertically because of the content. like this:
[image]
So you can see the bottom of two div are not aligned horizontally
.

**So my question is how to keep this to bottom always in a same line.**

Yeah maybe you will say: fill the all background to white then people cannot realize that. **But I need to keep the border lines and they should be in same line.**

My current code is like this(there are some dependencies, but they are just child components to generate data):

firstly,  my html file:

```
<div class="container-fluid vuln-content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2 filter-container">
      <div id="filter-card">
        <app-vuln-filter [currentSelectedTabIndex]="currentSelectedTabIndex"></app-vuln-filter>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
          <p-tabView (onChange)="onClick($event)" styleClass="vuln-tabs">
            <p-tabPanel *ngFor="let gridConfig of gridTabConfigs" id={{gridConfig.id}} header={{gridConfig.header}}>
              <app-vul-ami-grid [gridConfig]="gridConfig"></app-vul-ami-grid>
            </p-tabPanel>
          </p-tabView>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used some primeng tools like table, tab ..And you can see the 'col-2' part is the left, the 'col-10' part is the right.

also I have css file, it is kind of trival:

```
.vuln-content {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 37px);
  //height: calc(100vh - 35px);

  .filter-container {
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    background: #FFFFFF;
  }

  & > div.row {
    margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
  }
}
```

Maybe it need javascript(I use angular) to solve it? If so, absolutely fine. I like to learn javascript.

Comment: a dirty solution is to write some js to adapt the height of the div on the resize/zoom events so that it will be forced to fit

Comment: create an example on stackblitz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using Bootstrap.
In this case you can consider using flexbox, which will stretch your rows vertically and equally.
Here is the link to reference:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/#align-items
`<div class="d-flex align-items-stretch">...</div>`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this...

**html**

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="child">Content here</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parent {display: table}

#child {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: left;
}
```

The main takeaway here is that you need to vertical-align the button panel left...

Comment: it seems vertical-align didn't has left

Comment: @HongliBu here is a link to all the vertical aligns in CSS https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

Answer (score 1):

As @V.Volkov said, you are using Bootstrap. But in this case i would like to add more accurate code. Here I've added `align-items-stretch` class in `<div class="row">`, Because the `.row` class is already `display: flex` in Bootstrap CSS. This should work correctly:

```
<div class="container-fluid vuln-content">
  <div class="row align-items-stretch">
    <div class="col-2 filter-container">
      <div id="filter-card">
        <app-vuln-filter [currentSelectedTabIndex]="currentSelectedTabIndex"></app-vuln-filter>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
          <p-tabView (onChange)="onClick($event)" styleClass="vuln-tabs">
            <p-tabPanel *ngFor="let gridConfig of gridTabConfigs" id={{gridConfig.id}} header={{gridConfig.header}}>
              <app-vul-ami-grid [gridConfig]="gridConfig"></app-vul-ami-grid>
            </p-tabPanel>
          </p-tabView>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

OR you can set `align-items: stretch;` manually in your CSS.

```
.vuln-content {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 37px);
  //height: calc(100vh - 35px);

  .filter-container {
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    background: #FFFFFF;
  }

  & > div.row {
    margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
    align-items: stretch;
  }
}
```